# Login with MVC and stored procedure

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I created a login page, but I try to log in, the codes did go through the jQuery. But I have type in the correct password and user id but it keeps give me fail. So can someone help me ? I have tried this method before on another login page, it works but this time, it does not work.

//Web API

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody]testLogin LoginU)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] != null)
        {
            return Ok("LoggedIn");
        }
        else
        {
            using (Entities dbc = new Entities())
            {
                LogIn_Result result = dbc.LogIn(LoginU.id, LoginU.password).FirstOrDefault<LogIn_Result>();
                user currentUser = null;
                if (result != null)
                {
                    DbSet<user> dbs = dbc.users;
                    IQueryable<user> q = from s in dbs
                                            where s.id == result.id
                                         select s;
                    user = q.FirstOrDefault<user>();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = user;
                    return Ok("/Home/Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok("Failed");
                }

            }
        }
```

//jQuery

```
function performLogin() {
    var login = {
        userid: $("#TxtUserName").val(),
        password: $("#TxtPassword").val()
    };
    var apiUrl = "/api/HomeAPI";
    alert(login.password);
    alert(login.userid);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: apiUrl,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: login,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            if (result == "Failed") {
                $("#spanMsg").html("OMG FAILLLL");
            }
            else if (result == "LoggedIn") {
                $("#spanMsg").html("Another dude logon already");
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = result;
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#BtnLogin").click(function () {
        performLogin();
    });
});
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [LogIn]
    @id int,
    @password varchar(50) 
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[user]
    WHERE id = @id AND password = HASHBYTES('SHA1', @password)
```

if you need anything else do inform me.

My DB for user only got id (`int`), one FK (`int`), username (`varchar`) and password (`varbinary`).

Comment: in your webapi action method, is the variable LoginU getting the values you posted?

Comment: @KarthikMR Yes, it is getting the values i post. It just keep returning me fail messages.

Comment: @KarthikMR So sorry the values did not go through, I do not know where the link is broken

Comment: @KarthikMR I just fixed that bug already thank you for replying out of the 21 views :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the performLogin(), the variable used must be the same with the database.

```
function performLogin() {
var login = {
    id: $("#TxtUserName").val(),
    password: $("#TxtPassword").val()
};
```

So just change userid to id and it will work already :D